# using $.getJSON with JSCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JSCharts. I'm using $.getJSON to load  json files and 
with them i want to create charts with JSCharts. I am getting the message:

JSChart: Input data in wrong format for selected chart type

```
 var x= new Array();

 $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

  x.push(val[0].abs);
  x.push(val[1].ord)
});
 });

var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer', 'line');
myChart.setDataArray(x);
myChart.draw();
```

Any ideas how to change to format, so it can be accepted by jscharts?

Even if i pass them as integers they are not accepted.
Json looks like this:

```
   " cordonnee " : [ { " abs " : "45" } ,
                     { " ord " : "12" }
                   ],

     "autre" : [ { "abs": "68" } ,
                 { " ord " : "13" }
               ]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide the details of your test.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse the values as Integers.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {

  x.push(parseInt(val[0].abs));
  x.push(parseInt(val[1].ord));
});
```

Comment: I fact i had to do both use integers and a 2-dimensional array thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the data as a 1 dimensional array, it has to be 2 dimensional for a line chart.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   var y = new Array();
   y.push(val[0].abs);
   y.push(val[1].ord);
   x.push(y);

});
```

see [JSCharts how to use line graphs](http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use-line-graphs) for more details

Comment: I fact i had to do both use integers and a 2-dimensional array thanks very much